# How to prove that $f : [0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

I'm trying to show that the function

$$ f : [0,1] \to [0,1] \times [0,1] $$

$$ t=0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \dots \mapsto (0.t_1 t_3 t_5 \dots, 0.t_2 t_4 t_6 \dots ) $$

is continuous. My idea was to show that the function

$$ f_1 : [0,1] \to [0,1]  $$

$$ t=0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \dots \mapsto 0.t_1 t_3 t_5 \dots $$

Is continuous, and that would be sufficient. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does $ t=0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \dots $ mean? Expansion to which base? How to fix non-uniqueness of the expansion?

Comment: Well if $|t-s| < 10^{-m}$ then if $t_i$ are the digits of $t$ and $s_i$ are the digits of $s$ then $t_i = s_i$ for $i< m$.

Comment: Your function is undefined when $$t=0.100000000\dots=0.099999\dots$$ You might even find the function is not defined at such values, however you disambiguate it.

Comment: That's not true for all $t,$ @fleablood

Comment: Specifically, if $t=1/10,$ then on one side, $t-\epsilon$ will start $0.09999\dots$ and the other side $0.10000\dots.$ @fleablood

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think those are fixable.  However I worry about dismissing such concerns as "minor" or assuming they will work themselves out when in actuality such a function requires *great* care in it's very definition.  The statement "$t=0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \dots \mapsto (0.t_1 t_3 t_5 \dots, 0.t_2 t_4 t_6 \dots )"$ is far too informal and handwavy for my taste.  It certainly can be *made* well defined but IMO doing so and taking the work to do so is an essential part of actually *doing* the problem.

Comment: "That's not true for all t" Well, we'd have to make a case were the last several terms of one are $9$s and the other terms are all $0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know, how do you fix what? You can't fix this function and make it continuous. So what do you want to do? @Grant

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the function is not defined properly, you pointed out yourself. Can you help me fix it, so it is well defined?

Comment: Well, you just need to specify which decimal expansion to use when a number has two different decimal expansions. This is essentially any number of the form $n/10^m,$ where $n,m$ are natural numbers and $1\leq n\leq 10^m.$ But whatever choice you choose, the function won't be continuous. @Grant

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why isn't it continuous? Can you show that it isn't continuous?

Comment: Because $0.0999999111111\dots$ and $0.1000001111\dots$ are close together, and they map to $(0.0999111\dots,0.999111\dots)$ and $(0.10001111\dots,0.000111\dots)$ which are far apart in the second entry and don't get closer as we add more $0$ and $9$ values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152077/discussion-between-grant-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do use chat much because it doesn't work well on iPad. @Grant